# How to use TFS PowerShell to get list of changesets and associated work items?

Tags: powershell, tfs

I'm a novice with the PowerShell and TFS cmdlets and I'm trying to retrieve a list of changesets in an area path, and their associated work items.

I've got as far as listing changesets since a certain date:

```
Get-TfsItemHistory "$/Project/Branch" -Version “D01/12/10~” -Recurse
```

and also listing workitems since the same date:

```
Get-TfsItemHistory "$/Project/Branch" -Version "D01/12/10~" -Recurse | %{ $_.workitems }
```

Each query returns the same number of results, with the second query returning duplicate workitems.  This seems promising, as there are many changesets to workitems, so I assume I'm not far off combining the results.

Comment: What's module is for ***Get-TfsItemHistory*** cmdlet ?

Comment: @Kiquenet It's Team Foundation Server Power Tools; not included out of the box, but available here: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/search?term=team%20foundation%20server%20power%20tools&target=VS.  Choose the version which matches your instance.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, you're on the right track.  Try this as a way to view workitems associated with a changeset:

```
Get-TfsItemHistory "$/Project/Branch" -Version "D01/12/10~" -Recurse | 
    Select ChangesetId -exp WorkItems | 
    Format-Table Id,Title -GroupBy ChangesetId -Auto
```

Comment: Thanks, that gives me the data I need.  Is there any way to return it in one row per changeset, i.e. "ChangesetId, Owner, CreationDate, Comment, (workitem)Id, Title"?  Currently it comes out in sections.

Comment: Sure, get rid of the `-GroupBy` and specify just `Format-Table ChangesetId, Ownder, CreationDate, Comment, Id, Title -auto` but keep in that is a lot of stuff to put on one row.  You may need to widen your console or use `Format-Table ... -Auto | Out-String -Width 256`.

Comment: on executing this command i am getting `"Unable to determine the source control server"`

Comment: Either execute the command in a local dir mapped to a TFS team project. I think there is also a `Server` parameter on this command IIRC.  If so, then you can specify the server via that parameter.

Comment: http://deurell.github.io/articles/use-powershell-to-get-release-notes-from-tfs-builds/ using `QueryHistory` for get workitems list.

Answer (score 2):

Using `Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client` view https://stackoverflow.com/a/30047077/4051367

#### Usage

> $versionControlServer.QueryHistory

```
$vCSChangeSets = $versionControlServer.QueryHistory($locationToSearch, $latest, 0, $recursionType, $userName, $versionFrom, $versionTo, [int32]::MaxValue, $true ,$false, $false, $true) 
$TargetChangeSetChangeItems = @()  


$TargetChangeSetChangeItems = foreach ($vCSChangeSet in $vCSChangeSets) 
{   
    foreach ($vCSChange in $vCSChangeSet.Changes) 
    { 
        $vCSItem =  $vCSChange.Item 

        # MORE CODE HERE, OMMITTED
    }
}
```