# TFS Powershell Script for getting all unique changeset file-paths in a WorkItem tree given a WorkItem #

Tags: powershell, tfs

I am trying to create a PowerShell script where I could simply enter the `WorkItemID` and then get:

- a list of file-paths for all the changesets linked (via child/grand-child/grand-grand-child/... relationship)
- Remove duplicates from this list
- Output to a text file

Comment: we fix problems, not do your job for you.

Comment: Hi @svarog, sorry that the question came to you that way.I've been trying out the script in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4453177/how-to-use-tfs-powershell-to-get-list-of-changesets-and-associated-work-items but can't seem to get it to work. Also I understand that I will need to tweak it to get the results that I want. So this is more of a powershell newbie question.